# Azure AD B2C local user account locked-out notification

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using **Azure AD-B2C** user flow for sign-in/sign-up and looking for a feature where support users can get the event/callback/email if the user account is locked-out after unsuccessful login attempts.

Right now I am only able to manage the duration and attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Currently B2C don't support as it doesn't serve any purpose to notifying a user for smart lockout.

You could try using Azure Monitor and Event hubs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_8CjwtlzRDmYNKDj&Q_CHL=gl
>